# sf::st_intersection: virtually random error action

Tags: r, spatial, intersection, r-sf

I have a relatively simple task to accomplish in R: I have two polygon layers, a "patches" layer containing 39 focal polygons and a "landcover" layer containing one multipolygon of the focal landcover type. I need to clip those two layers so that I keep only the extent of the focal landcover type within the focal polygons. Sometimes, this works fine with `sf::st_intersection`, sometimes this works fine using `sf::st_difference`and a "negative" landcover layer (containing the extent of all non-focal landcover types) and sometimes none of both approaches work. At first, I thought that these different behaviors depend on the resulting topography complexitiy, but this does not seem to be the case.

The errors I get are of the form

> ```
> Error in CPL_geos_op2(op, st_geometry(x), st_geometry(y)) :    
> Evaluation error: TopologyException: Input geom 1 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 
> 4372482.6526834015 5297568.4303682083 at 4372482.6526834015 5297568.4303682083.
> ```

so I checked for the land cover polygon and each of the focal polygons using `sf:: st_is_simple ('patch')` which in all cases yielded `TRUE`.

Consider these three cases:

- The "simple" case, where `sf::st_intersection` works. An example (the
  patch in blue, the land cover in green): [image]

  `sf::st_intersection (focal_patch, focal_landcover)`:
  [image]
- The "intermediate" case, where `sf::st_intersection` does not work
  but `sf::st_difference` can be used as a workaround when the focal
  landcover is replaced by the non-focal land-cover. An example (the
  patch in blue, the non-focal land cover in red: [image]

  `sf::st_difference (patch, non-focal_landcover)` [image]
- The "difficult" case where neither keeping the focal land cover (green) type using `sf::st_intersection` nor excluding the non-focal land cover type (red) using `sf::st_difference` work - I get similar errors for both approaches:
  [image]

I was unable to make a reproducible example, so I hope that it is possible to figure out what happens here from the example images. I could not see any pattern in there so perhaps only someone with deep insights into `st_intersection` and `st_difference` can indiciate a solution to this...

Comment: The error says that the input topology is invalid. Did you check the validity of both inputs? I don't understand why you can't supply data for an example where the operation fails. It must be deterministic in the sense the with the same two inputs the same outcome happens, right?

Answer (score 4):

The error you are describing is not random; ring self intersection means invalid geometry. You should be able to test for it via `sf::st_is_valid()`.

This error is known to happen when using spatial objects originated in the realm of ESRI products, which use slightly different criteria for validity than OGC realm.

To overcome the issue you have several options:

- filter the offending geometry out (via subsetting of your spatial object based on the result of `sf::st_is_valid()` = leaving only valid geometries in place)
- try to correct the geometries via `sf::st_make_valid()` - note that this may result in altered geometry, and may require installation of `{lwgeom}` package
- apply "magic dust" of a buffer of zero width on your invalid spatial object via `sf::st_buffer(your_ object, 0)`. This hack will force creation of a new geometry, possibly overcoming the errors in the original one.

For more information consider the sf package documentation: https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/reference/valid.html

Comment: I somewhat knew that it was ESRIS fault here... The data I use are from a state authority, so I guess they use ESRI products. I thought `sf::st_is_simple` would check for validity, too (?). Very strange: I cannot reproduce the error anymore. I have not changed my data nor my skript, but now it works fine.

Comment: I really like problems that go away by themselves... rare as they are :) Have a look at this answer on our sister site, it explains the inconsistencies in a bit more of a detail https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119150/order-of-polygon-vertices-in-general-gis-clockwise-or-counterclockwise/147971#147971